# Akka Actor Creation Issue

Tags: akka

I am trying to create an actor that can be accessed remotely and locally.
The actor created below throws an exception. Any idea?

`val myLocalActor2 = system.actorOf(Props[ActorNodes], name =
"akka://JtsSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/MyOwnRef")`

Is this the best and only way to programmatically create and actor that is both local and remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" in actorOf is just a path segment. that will identify the newly created actor. See here for more information on that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/general/addressing.html

Also, having something which is both local and remote doesn't make sense, but I assume you mean that it should be local and be accessible from some remote node? If so, just create it with actorOf, and other nodes may look it up using "actorFor":

```
val remoteActor = system.actorFor("akka://CalculatorApplication@127.0.0.1:2552/user/simpleCalculator")
```

Read more about it here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/remoting.html

In general, please read the documentation, we've poured so many hours into it and it feels wasteful when people don't read it.

Comment: Hi Viktor, I meant indeed, "created locally" but available remotely and locally transparently. Therefore, I want to give a specific path to the actor a create locally so that I can look it up remotely. So indeed the question is how do I assign a path to my local actor using actorOf? The idea is also to broadcast this information so that remote clients to do need to explicitly know the location of the remote node but they could look it up in some kind of global registry? (And BTW I read the doc)

Comment: To have a global registry you need consensus, to get consensus you need some form of clustering. We're currently implementing a cluster solution for Akka, but for now you'll need to solve that by some other means of consensus.

Comment: Ok. Thx. I guess I'll use some kind of broadcast using jGroups.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working (apart for the global registry):

```
case class ActorMsg(val msg: String)

sealed class ActorNodes extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case ActorMsg(msg) => println("Actor Msg " + msg)
    case _ => println("Everything else")
  }
}

object JtsListener extends App {
  val sys = "JtsSystem"
  val system = ActorSystem(sys)
//  println("System: " + system.settings)

  val myLocalActor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ActorNodes], "MyLocalRef")
  println("MyLocalActor 1: " + myLocalActor1 + " has path " + myLocalActor1.path)
  myLocalActor1 ! new ActorMsg("Hello")

  val myLocalActor2 = system.actorFor("akka://"+sys+"@127.0.0.1:2552/user/MyLocalRef");
  println("MyLocalActor 2: " + myLocalActor2 + " has path " + myLocalActor2.path)
  myLocalActor2 ! new ActorMsg("Hello Again")
}
```

with application.conf (I am looking at doing this programmatically on ActorSystem

Thx.

The next step would be to broadcast that information so that all services are aware of where each actor is.. probably using the idea outlined there:

http://blog.vasilrem.com/even-simpler-scalability-with-akka-through-re